# how can I map port 10522 to 80 using apache for different host name?

Tags: apache-2.2, port, mapping

what I want is,

http://example.com:10522 is working perfect

I want apache to handle it like

http:\\test.example.com

10522 is another webserver not the apache web directory - its standalone web server running on port 10522

Comment: Have you looked at using Apache as a reverse proxy http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/reverse-proxy-apache.html or http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it on a firewall - redirect port 10522 to 80. In iptables, it could be:

```
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 10522 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 10522 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80
```

Access on test.example.com and test.example.com:10522 will be treated in the same VirtualHost and both will be seen as port 80.

But it's not clear from your question if it is what you want to accomplish. Not even what operating system you use. And what do you mean with "10522 is another webserver"?

**EDIT AFTER CLARIFICATION OF ANSWER:**

There can be at least two ways how to do it in Apache

- Mod_proxy and setting up reverse proxy for example.com:10522 as mentioned in another comments. With this, user will see test.example.com all the time
- Permanent redirection to example.com like this:

  RedirectPermanent / example.com:10522

  And user will be redirected to example.com:10522 at first access to test.example.com

Comment: no no I've already another application is running on port 80 - but its servername is different (domain)

for example - main is example.com:80 and test.example.com--> example.com:10522

Comment: Ok, so when user access http://test.example.com, it should serve http://example.com:10522, right? And on port 80 is Apache, and on port 10522 is another webserver, doesn't even have to be Apache, right?

Comment: yes exactly....

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to configure [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) on your Apache httpd to act as a reverse proxy for `test.example.com:10522`. The [basic examples](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#examples) in the documentation should be sufficient.

Comment: yes I know, but I'm not able to make it working anyhow, I've enabled the proxy module and tried but couldn't succeed !

Comment: What's the error message you encounter? What *exactly* doesn't work?